# Breezejs - get detailed error message in queries

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am working on an application with ASP.Net/MVC/EF/Breeze/Angular and it is working in my development environment. I just deployed it to my test environment and I am getting an error when I try to query breeze entity data. I don't think it's a DB connection problem, because I can query the breeze metadata successfully.

However, when I try to query for entity data, for example:

```
http://server/path/breeze/data/Cities
```

I get the following error:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

This shows up as a 500 error in the browser network history. Is there any way to get Breeze to return a more detailed error message? I am not getting this error in development so I can't debug it there. Or any suggestions as to what I should look for if I can get metadata but not data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out it was a connection string problem! I have no idea how breeze was generating metadata without a DB connection. Maybe it caches it in a local file?

Anyways, it would be nice to be able to get more detailed messages in cases like this. Since breeze returns IQueryable<T> I couldn't see any obvious way to catch the exception and send back a message myself...